# Чем заменить устаревший метод System.IO.FileAccess

Tags: c#

```
 private static void WriteAlternateStream(string _path, string _text)
{
    var stream = CreateFileW(_path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(stream,FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.Write(_text);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
public static void Id(string _PathExe)
{
    var x = _PathExe + ":Zone.Identifier";
    WriteAlternateStream(x, "[ZoneTransfer]\r\nZoneId=1");
}
```

У меня выскакивает:

`Предупреждение 1   "System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(System.IntPtr, System.IO.FileAccess)" является устаревшим: "This constructor has been deprecated.  Please use new FileStream(SafeFileHandle handle, FileAccess access) instead.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202"`

Можно ли это заменить?

**Добавил текст**

Я обычно импортировал:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW")]
public static extern System.IntPtr CreateFileW(
[InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName,
uint dwDesiredAccess,uint dwShareMode,
[InAttribute()] IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
uint dwCreationDisposition,
uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
[InAttribute()] IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Но если заменить его на:

```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
  uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
  uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

То получаю ошибку в `var stream = CreateFileW(` что:

`Элемент "CreateFileW" не существует в текущем контексте.`

**Решение проблемы**

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFileW(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
  uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
  uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Comment: `var stream = CreateFileW(` - проще было бы заменить на `var stream = CreateFile(`

Answer (score 3):

Прямо в сообщении об ошибке сказано, на что нужно заменить вызов - на перегрузку, которая принимает `SafeFileHandle` вместо `IntPtr`. Соответственно, вам нужно использовать другое объявление `CreateFile`:

```
// Use interop to call the CreateFile function.
// For more information about CreateFile,
// see the unmanaged MSDN reference library.
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
  uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
  uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Полный пример есть в [MSDN по `SafeFileHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle(v=vs.110).aspx).